# how to break a second foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Actually in this code I tried to show the `form label` and `form input` field come dynamic from the database.

- In this first foreach loop contains a `label`
- Second, foreach contain the `input` fields data.

If the second foreach have no data, both foreach not work what should I do?

```
@section('body') 

     <!--{{session('uid')}} -->

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!--      Wizard container        -->
             <div class="wizard-container">
                <div class="card wizard-card" data-color="red" id="wizard">
                   <form action="{{URL::to('faculty/submitreport')}}" method="post" name="reportform">
                       <!--        You can switch " data-color="blue" "  with one of the next bright colors: "green", "orange", "red", "purple"             -->
                        {{ csrf_field()}}
                        <div class="wizard-header">
                           <h3 class="wizard-title">
                               Monthly Progress Report
                           </h3>
                           <h5>This information will let us know more about you.</h5>
                         </div>

                    @foreach($fetchform as $data)
                      @foreach($fetchans as $ans)

                        @if(is_null($ans)){
                           @break

                           <div class="wizard-navigation">
                              <ul>
                                <li><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">{{$data->f_title}}</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>

                           <div class="tab-content">
                              <div class="tab-pane" id="details">
                                 <div class="row">                  
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                       @if(is_null($data->f1))
                                       @else

                                        <div class="form-group label-floating">                                    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f1}}</label>
                                             <input name="f1" type="text" class="form-control"value='{{$ans->f1}}'></input>     
                                        </div>
                                       @endif                                       

                            @if(is_null($data->f2))
                            @else
                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f2}}</label>
                                    <input name="f2" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f2}}'></input>     
                                </div>
                            @endif          

                            @if(is_null($data->f3))
                            @else
                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f3}}</label>
                                    <input name="f3" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f3}}'></input>     
                                </div>
                            @endif          

                            @if(is_null($data->f4))
                            @else
                              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f4}}</label>
                                    <input name="f4" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f4}}'></input>     
                               </div>
                            @endif          

                            @if(is_null($data->f5))
                            @else
                               <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f5}}</label>
                                    <input name="f5" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f5}}'></input>     
                               </div>
                            @endif          

                            @if(is_null($data->f6))
                            @else
                               <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f6}}</label>
                                    <input name="f6" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f6}}'></input>     
                               </div>
                            @endif          

                            @if(is_null($data->f7))
                            @else
                               <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f7}}</label>
                                    <input name="f7" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f7}}'></input>     
                               </div>
                            @endif          

                            @if(is_null($data->f8))
                            @else
                               <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f8}}</label>
                                    <input name="f8" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f8}}'></input>     
                               </div>
                            @endif          

                            @if(is_null($data->f9))
                            @else
                               <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <b> <label class="control-label">{{$data->f9}}</label></b>
                                    <input name="f9" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f9}}'></input>     
                               </div>
                           @endif           

                           @if(is_null($data->f10))
                           @else
                               <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                 <b>    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f10}}</label></b>
                                    <input name="f10" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f10}}'></input>       
                               </div>
                           @endif           

                           @if(is_null($data->f11))
                           @else
                               <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                  <b>       <label class="control-label">{{$data->f11}}</label> </b>
                                    <input name="f11" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f11}}'></input>       
                               </div>
                           @endif           

                           @if(is_null($data->f12))
                           @else
                              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                 <b>    <label class="control-label">{{$data->f12}}</label></b>
                                    <input name="f12" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$ans->f12}}'></input>       
                              </div>
                           @endif

                           <input type='hidden' name="f_id" value='{{$data->f_id}}'>
                           <input type='hidden' name="u_id" value='{{session()->get("uid")}}'>
                           <input type='hidden' name="f_status" id="f_status" />
                    </div>
                   }
                 @endif                                 
              @endforeach
            @endforeach  

         </div>
        </div>
       </div>       
     </div>

     <div class="wizard-footer">
          <div class="pull-right">
              <input type='submit' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd-lg' name='save' value='Save' />
               <input type='button' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd-lg' onclick="myFunction()" name='Submit' value='submit' />
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
 </div> <!-- wizard container -->
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    var r = confirm("Really Do You Want To Finally Submit a Form \n After Submitting You Can't Update Anything into It.");
    if (r == true) {
        document.getElementById("f_status").value = '1';
        reportform.submit();
    } else {

    }

}
</script>
```

@endsection

Comment: sometimes its good to preview your question before and after posting (that's just to make it looks better and can attract interest from others)

Comment: Just an FYI, instead of writing an if else blocks with an empty if section you could put `!` in front of the condition and remove the else e.g. `@if( ! is_null($data->f12)) ... @endif`. Alternatively, blade also comes with `@unless` e.g. @unless(is_null($data->f12)) ... @endunless

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code, it looks like you are trying to fill the `label` elements with the values of the `$data` variable and the `input` fields with the value of the `$ans` variable. As the code is written right now, you are looping through all the items in `$fetchform` and each time you loop you go through all the values of `$fetchans`. So if you had 3 form items and 3 answers you would actually run 9 loops. You're getting every possible combination of values.

It seems more likely that each `fetchform` has a corresponding `fetchans`. If this is the case, continuing with the example above, you would only want run 3 loops. If I were to write this code, I would have it look something like this:

```
    //loop through all items in $fetchform
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($fetchform); $i++)
        //php tags needed in blade to set the variables
        @php 
            $data = $fetchform[$i]; //get the form data
            $ans = $fetchans[$i]; //get the corresponding form answer
        @endphp

        //it might be more appropriate to check these for 'empty' instead of null
        //that all depends on your code
        @if(!is_null($data) || !is_null($ans))

            //make sure object has the 'f1' key and value is not null
            @if(array_key_exists('f1', $data) && !is_null($data->f1))
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                    <label class="control-label">{{ $data->f2 }}</label>
                    <input name="f2" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{ $ans->f2 }}' />     
                </div>
            @endif
        @endif
    @endfor
```

Keep in mind that the code above makes a few assumptions about your question. First, it assumes that `$fetchform` and `$fetchans` are numerical arrays that can be accessed by the `$i` value. Second, it assumes that `$fetchform` and `$fetchans` have corresponding key values, so the data and answers are both at the same numerical key in their respective arrays. Finally, it assumes that the values, when not present will be `null` versus being `empty`, which I would think is more likely the case. You may have to modify the code I provided to fit your exact needs. Play with it and see if it works.